# What form(s) of math does this machine learning course indicate as needed?

Tags: self-learning, machine-learning

Below image is from a PDF attached to a machine learning course by Manning Publications ([this one](https://www.manning.com/livevideo/reinforcement-learning-in-motion)).

Other than that image, the course description does not explicitly state what areas of mathematics are required for it.

In that image I do recognize some set theory notation. But besides that, if a person wanted to prepare to understand the course material better, what areas of math should they study?

[image]

Comment: Bayesian inference is statistics and probability theory. In general I've found multivariable calculus, linear algebra and statistics to be the most useful background for machine learning.

Comment: Probabilty theory